# Adding object arrays from diffrerent api responses

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on a React Native app where i'm using `FlatList`. The data i'm showing in the `FlatList` are coming from API response. Now, the API throws different data each time on a button click. I want to add all the responses after button press and show in the `FlatList`. I have done till this part here:

```js
state = {
count: 1,
newArr: []
};

onScrollEndDrag = async () => {
this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
return await fetch(
    `$myAPI/products/` + `?page=${this.state.count}`
)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        this.setState({ newArr: json })
        return json;
    })
    .catch(error => warn(error));
}

render(){
const list = [data1, data2, data3]
return (
    <Fragment>
        <FlatList
            key={this.key}
            data={[...list, ...this.state.newArr]}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            scrollEventThrottle={1}
        />

        <Button title='Load More' onPress={this.onScrollEndDrag}></Button>
    </Fragment>
)
}
```

It shows the list. But doesn't show the added `newArr`. How this can be done that on pressing Load newer response will be added to the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this line

`this.setState({ newArr: json })`

You're replacing the previous data with the newer one. Change it to merge with the previous data.

`this.setState({ newArr: [...this.state.newArr, ...(json || [])] })`

Comment: Yes, it's working. It adds the newArr. But does not renders to the app. Can you say why it's not rendering? @SirajAlam

Comment: Well, that you have to debug. As you're saying the data is populating into the newArr, so check how many times `renderItem` is running. It should be equal to the length of the newArra, and if it is, then your this problem is resolved, and there's a different problem that need to be check.

Comment: Also, I had a typo in my answer, fixed it. Can you check again?

Comment: Yaah i tried fixing the typo already. How to i check how many times renderItem is running by the way? Do, i have to rerender in some way to show newArr data in the app?

Comment: Just add a console statement, it will log as many times as the function called.

Comment: Yaah. Render count remains 10 because i have 10 items in List array. But newArr does not count for some reason.

Comment: There's no other way you try to re-render the newArr, what you have done is right, the problem is something else.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your data keeps getting reset/changed everytime your render function is called. why don't you keep `newArr` as your source of truth for your data?
Try the following:

```
state = {
count: 1,
newArr: [data1, data2, data3]
};

onScrollEndDrag = async () => {
this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
return await fetch(
    `$myAPI/products/` + `?page=${this.state.count}`
)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        this.setState({ newArr: [...newArr, json] })
        return json;
    })
    .catch(error => warn(error));
}

render(){
return (
    <Fragment>
        <FlatList
            key={this.key}
            data={this.state.newArr}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            scrollEventThrottle={1}
        />

        <Button title='Load More' onPress={this.onScrollEndDrag}></Button>
    </Fragment>
)
}
```

Comment: Actually i already have a list to render. I need to add newArr data to the list when they are coming on button press from the API. @NikhilAsrani